# Tag SVN Repository with SVN.exe at Command Line

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was looking through the various invocations of svn.exe but I'm not seeing a way to tag a repository at the command line. Does anyone know of a command to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "tag" is just a directory copied from another directory, and (by convention) placed in a "tags" directory.

So the command you are looking for is just [svn copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html).